# How can I disable fail on warning when using GCC and Make?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, ada

I'm trying to build GCC for use with an [AVR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR) microcontroller and avr-ada, and I've hit a roadblock caused by my regular compiler being too picky about the version I needed for the AVR.  I get the following warning, which in turn causes GCC or Make to report an error:

```
gcc -c -g -O2 -gnatpg -gnata -nostdinc -I- -I. -Iada
  -I../../gcc/ada ../../gcc/ada/exp_ch5.adb -o ada/exp_ch5.o
exp_ch5.adb:177:16: warning: function "Has_Address_Clause" is not referenced
make[2]: *** [ada/exp_ch5.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is there a way to instruct GCC or Make to not fail on warnings?

Comment: I don't think any of the debug options result in treating warnings as errors (at least not that I could find), is that the full output?

Comment: Normally (when not using `-gnatg` to apply all the checks required for a compiler build), GNAT (Ada in GCC) uses `-gnatwe` to treat warnings as errors, and `-gnatwn` to cancel that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trigger here is the -gnatpg (actually, the -gnatg): this is the "GNAT implementation mode (used for compiling GNAT units)". -gnatp means "suppress all checks".

I'm not sure of the full effect of -gnatg, though it certainly causes warnings to be treated as errors -- like -Werror -- at any rate while building the compiler itself; I think I remember seeing non-fatal warnings while building the RTS.

One possibility would be to compile just exp_ch5.adb by hand without -gnatg; the command you list was issued at gcc/, so

```
$ cd gcc
$ gcc -c -g -O2 -gnatp -gnata -nostdinc -I- -I. -Iada -I../../gcc/ada \
  ../../gcc/ada/exp_ch5.adb -o ada/exp_ch5.o
```

Then back up one level, and 'make' again.

This is a cross-compiler, so you won't (I hope!) need to repeat this for all three stages of a full build.

Comment: Thank you, your solution allowed me to get past the above error.  I have more warnings from the Ada compiler, but I'll tread along now!

Comment: What is "RTS"? [Runtime system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_system)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, yes.

Answer (score 54):

Try `make -k` instead of just `make`.  That will 'continue' rather than stop.

Answer (score 15):

As an alternative to diving into the build system, try setting [`-Wno-error`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror) in CFLAGS, which you should be able to do through the environment (or at configure time, if using the GNU build system).

Answer (score 5):

It seems the [-Werror](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror) flag is set in the Makefile. Maybe you can look for the CFLAGS options in the Makefile and remove the -Werror flag. The Werror flag will make all warnings into errors.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it is not a good idea to ignore warnings from your compiler. However, if this is a portion of a larger make process there is likely a `-Werror` flag inserted earlier in the sequence. Start by looking for that.

After looking around, there seems to be a wealth of flags to control warnings while compiling Ada code. For instance, `-gnatwF` will *Suppress warnings on unreferenced formals* according to [this guide](http://www.adacore.com/wp-content/files/auto_update/gnat-unw-docs/html/gnat_ugn_4.html#SEC42). Possibly the switch you require can be found in the list provided there.

Comment: Yeah, nothing in what he pasted would have resulted in -Werror being turned on. It had to be prior to the excerpt.

Comment: I know its not a good idea, and I tried building an older version of gcc/gnat (gcc-4.3.2) just so that I could build the AVR gcc/gnat (also gcc-4.3.2), but I was running into the exact same problem there too.  After talking with the project owner, he told me my system Ada compiler (gcc-4.3.4) "smells too new" for the code base, and my options were to hack the source code or try to override the fail or warning.

Comment: Well, I remember dealing with Ada for a brief time and, for me, the approach would have to be augmenting the build. As I recall Ada is right finicky about things.

Comment: Again, I agree with what you are saying.  I'll try some of the options you listed as well as others in this thread when I get home today, but I'm learning towards just using the Windows version since I can easily get a binary and get to work.

Answer (score 1):

In gcc configure you can add `--disable-werror`.

Though it's advisable to seek out a proper patch first.

Comment: It does not work for me:

# gcc  --disable-werror  -Werror -Wall foo.c
cc1: error: unknown pass werror specified in -fdisable

Comment: What is *"gcc configure"*?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building (*"Last seen more than 9 years ago"*). Perhaps somebody else can chime in?

Comment: [Using executable `./configure`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132594/disable-werror-in-configure-file) (whatever that is)?

Comment: OK, [./configure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script) is associated with Make (has nothing to do with GCC as such).

Answer (score 0):

Put "pragma warnings(off, "...")" into the offending parts of your code.

See http://www.adacore.com/2007/11/19/ada-gem-18/.

Comment: The link is broken: *"The page you're looking for can't be found"*

Comment: Re "`pragma warnings`": Do you mean something like [`#pragma GCC diagnostic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#index-pragma_002c-diagnostic)?