# Getting errors when compiling code using makefile. Works using console

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu

I am getting compilation errors when building my project with a makefile which I don't see when building using console.

I am using the prebuilt GNU toolchain for PowerPC.

Here is my makefile,

```
GCC_Assembler = powerpc-eabi-as
GCC_Compiler  = powerpc-eabi-gcc

Directory_Application :=$(argument)/Source_Files
Directory_Bootloader :=$(argument)/Source_Files
Directory_RAMBootloader :=$(argument)/Source_Files

Application_Source_Files := $(wildcard $(Directory_Application)/*.C)
Application_Source_Files_Objecs=$(Application_Source_Files:.C=.O)


default:  Build_Application
all:   Build_Application

Build_Application: $(Application_Source_Files_Objecs)


$(Application_Source_Files_Objecs) : %.O: %.C
$(GCC_Compiler)  -c $<   -o $@ -O1  -Wall -Wfatal-errors
```

It builds without errors when I try to build it using these commands.

```
CD %WORKSPACE%\Source Files
powerpc-eabi-gcc    debug.c       -c -odebug.o    -O1 -Wall -Wfatal-errors
powerpc-eabi-gcc    io.c          -c -oio.o       -O1 -Wall -Wfatal-errors
...
...
```

So, when building using makefile, I get an error for a function that is not declared correctly. See the image below

[Error( Makefile )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSboe.png)

```
/Debug.C: infunction 'void display_task_table()':
/Debug.C:627:18: error: 'task_wait' was not declared in this scope
task_wait(100*2);
```

I only get warning for the same function when compiling without makefile.

[Warning( Console )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybEXt.png)

```
Debug.C: in function 'display_task_table':
Debug.c:627:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'task_wait' [-    Wimplicit-function-declaration]
task_wait(100*2);
```

I can fix the error by including the proper header file, but I would like to know why?

Please let me know if I need to include anything else

Comment: Please post the errors in your question itself, not as images.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the signature for your `task_await` function

Comment: If you don't want the makefile to fail on a warning, see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414242/gcc-make-how-to-disable-fail-on-warning

Comment: Older C standards allowed implicit functions declarations. In newer version of the standard, like C99, C11 (and in C++), it is an error. So my best bet is that when you compile in the console you are compiling in C89 mode. From the information provided I don't know why you get different results. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182763/implicit-function-declarations-in-c

Comment: Is there anyway to force the makefile to use C89. I tried -std=c89 flag, but it is still giving the error.

Comment: I think the main question here is what is the difference between manual invocation of gcc and when the gcc is invoked by make. I see no difference at least in command line arguments so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are using `.C` extension when compiling with the Makefile, so the compiler is interpreting the file as a C++ source file and in C++, not having a prototype is an error (and only a warning in C)  Just rewrite the line

```
$(Application_Source_Files_Objecs) : %.O: %.C
```

to

```
$(Application_Source_Files_Objecs) : %.o: %.c
```

and try again (and don't use an Operating System that doesn't distinguish case of letters :) **<---** this was a joke, don't flame, please)

## EDIT

Please, do the same with all the lines that specify `.C` and `.O` files also to `.c` and `.o` instead.  The operating system doesn't bother with the case of characters, but `make(1)` and `gcc(1)` do.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks a lot.